# In R: How to create a vector of lagged differences but keep the original value for negative differences without using loops

Tags: r, replace, diff, lag

I have a vector in R of the form:

```
> a <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,1,3,5,7,9,11,1,3,5,7,9,11)
> a
 [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11  1  3  5  7  9 11  1  3  5  7  9 11
```

I can take the lagged differences like this:

```
b <- diff(a)
> b
 [1]   2   2   2   2   2 -10   2   2   2   2   2 -10   2   2   2   2   2
```

But I would like the negative differences to be replaced by the original values in the vector `a`. Or, in this case the `-10`'s to be replaced by the `1`'s.

Is there a way to do this without looping though the vectors?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way:

```
    indices<-which(b<0)
    b[indices]<-a[indices+1]
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

- One approach using replacement:

  ```
  d <- diff(a)
  d_neg <- d < 0
  d[d_neg] <- a[-1][d_neg]
  # [1] 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2
  ```
- One approach using `ifelse`:

  ```
  d <- diff(a)
  ifelse(d < 0, a[-1], d)
  # [1] 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2
  ```
- One approach using mathematics and `pmax`:

  ```
  d <- diff(a)
  (d < 0) * a[-1] + pmax(d, 0)
  # [1] 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2
  ```